# How to append elements into empty list

Tags: python

I am trying to append elements into empty list. using list.append() method. script gives recent value, But not appending to list.

I have tried below script it is giving updated value.

```
for i in range(10):
    x = []
    if i > 1:
        x.append(i)
print (x)
```

Output : [9]

Expected output : [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

Could you please help me why i am getting this output and how to resolve it?

Comment: You create new list in every iteration. All that are added get replaced.

Comment: `range(2, 10)` will produce sequence you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create new list in every iteration because it replaces the old data with a new list:

```
x = []    
for i in range(10):
    if i > 1:
        x.append(i)
print (x)
```

However, there is a simpler way to do this:

```
[i for i in range(10) if i > 1]
```

Output:

> ```
> [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
> ```

Comment: You can add `x = list(range(2, 10))`

Comment: @OlvinRoght I know but it doesn't fulfill the OP needs. OP might have just showed an example input